# React intl return [object Object]

Tags: reactjs, internationalization, react-intl

I am trying to use react intl to translate the page of my site. [Github](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl)

json lang :

```
fr.json : 
{
    "errorPage.title": Erreur 404"
}

en.json : 
{
    "errorPage.title": Error 404"
}
```

I have that on my js file

```
const title = <FormattedMessage id="errorPage.title" defaultMessage="Erreur 404" />

document.title = title;
```

That return on my title page this [object Object]

How i can do ?
Thank's !

Answer (score 0):

Since the key contains . Notation you need to access key like

```
object["errorPage.title"]
```

Also the json key value you posted has double quotes missing in the start

You need to do something like below to make it work

```
const object = {
     "errorPage.title": "Error 404"
}

const title = object["errorPage.title"];
document.title = title;
```

Comment: I've edit my post, i'm using library for translate my website, i can't declare variable like this...

Comment: FormatedMessage from to react-intl : https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/blob/master/src/components/message.js

Comment: Can you post your detailed json Lang?

Comment: It's on the main question, i've only this on my json files. React intl translate string according to the browser langage.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but maybe the answer can help someone.

The `FormattedMessage` is a React component that provides a declarative way of using localized messages. Therefore, the value of the variable `title` (from the question) is not a string but an object.

To achieve this, you should imperatively use the `react-intl` ([official doc](https://formatjs.io/docs/react-intl/api#why-imperative-api)).

```
const title = intl.formatMessage({ id: "errorPage.title", defaultMessage: "Erreur 404" });

document.title = title;
```

You can find more examples of the `react-intl` imperative and declarative way of the usage [here](https://localizely.com/blog/react-intl-tutorial/).